# v-text-field Not added on v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to add one v-text-field and it doesn't allow me
enable the slot I want to know that I am missing 
I have all the values ​​in the header

```
    <v-data-table  v-model="pagos.prestamosPagosDetalleList" :headers="headers" item-key="numeroCuota" show-select :single-select="singleSelect" :items="prestamoDetalle" class="elevation-1">
                   <template slot="items" scope="props">
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{ props.item.numeroCuota }}</td>
                      <td>{{ props.item.montoCuota }}</td>
                      <td>{{ props.item.balanceCuota }}</td>
                      <td>{{ props.item.abono }}</td>
                      <td>{{ props.item.moraCuota }}</td>
                      <td>{{ props.item.interesCuota }}</td>
                      <td>{{ props.item.pendiente }}</td>
                      <td>{{ props.item.total_pagado }}</td>
                      <td>{{ props.item.fechaCuota}}</td>
                      <td><v-text-field v-model="props.item.abono"></v-text-field></td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
    </v-data-table>

 headers: [
        { text: "Numero de Cuota", value: "numeroCuota" },
        { text: "Monto", value: "montoCuota" },
        { text: "Balance", value: "balanceCuota" },
        { text: "Abono", value: "abono" },
        { text: "Mora", value: "moraCuota" },
        { text: "Interes", value: "interesCuota" },
        { text: "Pendiente", value: "pendiente" },
        { text: "Total Pagado", value: "total_pagado" },
        { text: "Fecha Cuota", value: "fechaCuota" }
      ]
```

Comment: could you please add your headers? perhaps you missed to add one header for the additional column.

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern, I resolved it with this ---> v-slot:item.abono="{ item }"

```
 <template v-slot:item.abono="{ item }">
                 <v-text-field type="number" v-model.number="item.abono"></v-text-field>
 </template>
```